# Слово «доктор» (ученая степень)

Tags: выбор-слов

Слово *доктор* в современном русском языке полисемантическое. Главное значение — это врач. У большинства людей именно такие ассоциации при употреблении этого слова. Как, например, малограмотный носитель языка может понять, что доктор Геббельс вовсе не врач, а ученый, получивший такую научную степень? Но дело в другом: мне интересно, какая здесь связь между врачом и ученым?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Доктор" образовано от латинского глагола docere (обучать) и буквально означает "ученый". Отсюда доктора наук. Врачей так стали называть, чтобы показать, что это человек получивший медицинское образование, а не знахарь какой-нибудь. Напомню, что "врач" этимологически родственен слову “врать" - это тот, кто заговаривает болезни.

Answer (score 2):

Слово "доктор" происходит от латинского глагола doceo - "учу", "обучаю" и буквально значит "учёный" В последствии слово  в разговорной речи приобрело значение ‘врач’, то есть ‘учёный врач’ — в отличие от простых недипломированных лекарей или знахарей.